# Как получить android:layout_width из разметки?

Tags: java, android, layout, customview

Как получить дефолтные параметры из layout'а с кастомным элементом.

Активность с кастомным элементом

```
<com.example.custombutton.CustomButton
    android:id="@+id/jjs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    custom:text_size="199"/>
```

Класс кастомного элемента

```
public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context, attributeSet);

    mContext = context;

    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CustomButtonAttrs);
    int mRadiusHeight = attributes.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomButtonAttrs_android_layout_width, 0);
    Log.i("CustomButton", mRadiusHeight + "");
}
```

Не знаю как это может помочь, но оставлю здесь.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomButtonAttrs">
        <attr name="text_size" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: `.getWidth()` ?

Comment: .getWidth() возвращает 0

Comment: Это происходит потому что Вы запрашиваете ширину в тот момент, когда вьюшка еще не отрисована. Чтобы убедиться в этом, можете запросить ширину при нажатии на кнопку, например.

Comment: Хорошо, существует несколько вариантов констркутора.
Напрмер, 
    public CustomButton(Context context){...}
И, например, public CustomButton(Context context, attrs AttributeSet){..}
Наверное, можно извлекать стандартные параметры из attrs, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Не ошибаетесь, параметры, установленные в layout можно получить из `AttributeSet`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, разобрался)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все правильно делаете, но есть одно но: так как у вью значение атрибута задано `match_parent`, а в момент вызова конструктора эта вью еще не отрисована, то `mRadiusHeight` будет `0`.

Ширину (как и высоту) вьюшки можно получить с помощью методов `getWidth()` и `getHeight()` соответственно.

Актуальные ширина и высота вьюшки будут доступны только после ее отрисовки. Например, методы `getWidth()` и `getHeight()`, вызванные в методе `onCreate(...)` будут возвращать нулевые значения, так как в этот момент вью еще не отрисована.

Отследить момент отрисовки вью можно, например, с помощью `OnGlobalLayoutListener`:

```
someView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int width = someView.getWidth();
    }
});
```

После получения параметров вью, не забудьте удалить установленный `OnGlobalLayoutListener`.